# WPF: Button if clicked runs a new query and updates the DataGrid with the new query

Tags: c#, database, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

What I want to do is access the database via a query (already have one made, but heres the issue:

```
namespace WpfApp3
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ViewData : Window
    {
        public ViewData()
        {
            InitializeComponent();           
        }

        private void ShowData(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CustomerEntities1 db = new CustomerEntities1();            
            if (report.IsInitialized)
            {
                var report = from values in db.Customers
                             select values;
                valueGrid.ItemsSource = report.ToList();
            }
            else if (sortName.IsInitialized)
            {
                var sortName = from values in db.Addresses                              
                               select values;
                valueGrid.ItemsSource = sortName.ToList();
            }
        }



    }
}
```

I Do not understand how the bindings in WPF work, and Im having issues when running the code. It only runs the top portion of the if condition. Any ideas what binding I should use where if clicked, it is considered true, and runs the condition when met. Once the condition is met, it should remove the old one, and replace it with the new query for the DataGrid. Thank You

Comment: Your statement " It only runs the top portion of the if condition." - Does this mean always if condition is being executed i.e. control is going inside the if condition always? And who calls ShowData() method? What do you mean by " where if clicked...." Could not able to relate it. Share your xaml  as well.

Answer (score 0):

So in WPF the UI Components (`valueGrid`) in your case are usually notified if the Data changes (`CustomerEntities1`) on Initialization and IF and ONLY IF the Source implements [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=net-6.0) . you should therefore consider implementing this interface in ally or ViewModels, assuming you are using the MVVM pattern.

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas what Binding I should use

The way your code is set up you can't use bindings at all but you would want a oneWay binding if all you do is populate your DataGrid from code.

If you want to use Data binding you need to set the DataContext of your Window to something like

```
DataContext = this;
```

This will allow you to bind properties that you declare in your code behind to UI controls in your .xaml code like this:

`<TextBlock Text="{Binding PropertyName}"/>`

Now this might work syntax wise but your DataGrid still won't update because your DataContext class or any of their parent classes need to Implement the *INotifyPropertyChanged* Interface.

I advise you to start reading about the basics of Data binding and work through a tutorial or two. Because even if you follow what I've written above and you get it to work it is not the ideal approach to this problem.
You'd want to set up a type of class known as *ViewModel* that will be have all the properties that hold the data you want to show in your *View* (the Window) and have it as the Datacontext.

This link will give you a good overview of what data binding is, what you can do and how get it to work.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-6.0